# Как получить данные

Tags: python

У меня есть: `[(1, 6211102636, '2023-08-01 19:50:23.373509', 'Jame', 1, 100, 10)]`
как получить данные в переменную?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите из кортежа внутри списка получить просто список:

```py
a = [(1, 6211102636, '2023-08-01 19:50:23.373509', 'Jame', 1, 100, 10)]
b = list(a[0])
print(b)
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 6211102636, '2023-08-01 19:50:23.373509', 'Jame', 1, 100, 10]
```

Ещё можно так:

```
b = list(*a)
```

Comment: Как вы умудрились понять что нужно автору?? :)

Comment: @nchistov Не только лишь я ))  Ну, я ж аналитик, а не только программист )

Answer (score 2):

```
print([el for el in [(1, 6211102636, '2023-08-01 19:50:23.373509', 'Jame', 1, 100, 10)][0]])


[1, 6211102636, '2023-08-01 19:50:23.373509', 'Jame', 1, 100, 10]
```